# Clopen subsets in topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology

I have this problem and am not sure where to start:

Say $$A = \{(0,0),(0,1)\} \cup \bigcup^∞_{n=1}  S_n$$ is a subset of the euclidean plane that inherits the standard topology from said plane.

Here $S_n = \{(\frac1n, y) : 0 \le y \le 1\}$ for all $n\ge1$. Then let $B$ be a non empty subset of $A$, and $B$ is clopen in $A$.

The objective is to show that if $B$ contains either $(0,0)$ or $(0,1)$, then it contains both. I don't understand where to go or where to start here. Constructing a set where the complement is open is proving tough, and even then I don't see how that relates to anything.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a clopen set cannot intersect a connected set partially. That is, if $B$ is clopen and $S$ is connected then $U:=B\cap S\ne\emptyset$ and $V:=B^c\cap S\ne\emptyset$ is impossible. Otherwise, $U,V$ are open sets in $S$ (by definition of open set in the subspace $S$), they are non-empty, they are disjoint, and their union is $S$; by definition this would make $S$ disconnected. (In particular, if $B\cap S\ne\emptyset$ then $V=\emptyset$ and so $S\subseteq B$.)

In the question, we are given a clopen set $B$ in $A$. Each line $S_n$ is connected (in the standard topology), so $B$ cannot partially intersect it, by the above. For each $n$, either $S_n\subseteq B$ or $S_n\cap B=\emptyset$.

Now suppose $(0,0)\in B$. Since $B$ is open, $(0,0)$ is an interior point of it, meaning that there is a small ball $C$ centered at $(0,0)$ such that $C\cap A\subseteq B$. But any such ball intersects all $S_n$ for $n\ge N$ (for some $N$). Thus $S_n\subseteq B$ for $n\ge N$. Hence, $(\frac{1}{n},1)\in S_{n}$ is a sequence in $B$ (at least for $n\ge N$), converging to $(0,1)$. As $B$ is closed, $(0,1)\in B$.

Comment: Why exactly would B intersecting it cause disconnectedness?

Comment: Since $B\cap S_n$ is a clopen subset of $S_n$, what can it be?

Comment: @Ruy ah is this because $S_n$ is a collection of discrete lines? Partial intersection would cause some of these lines to be disconnected? I'm struggling to see the consequences of the closedness of $B$.

Comment: @ThunderHex (i) Since $B\cap S_n$ is clopen in $S_n$. A connected set (such as $S_n$) cannot contain a non-trivial clopen subset. That subset would have to be either $\emptyset$ or the whole space $S_n$. (ii) The closedness of $B$ is used both in asserting it is clopen and in containing its limit points $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Chrystomath I have been told that I should prove $B \cap S_n \neq 0$ then $S_n ⊆ B$, but would you be able to explain a bit further about how connected sets can't contain non-trivial clopen sets, and how $B∩Sn$  is clopen in $Sn$? I' ve looked over my lecture material and there isn't an explanation for this. I could understand Ruy's explanation in terms of intersecting each $S_n$, but is each line disjoint? In addition, if a closed set must contain its limit points, why would "$U$ must contain $(0,0)$ and $(0,1$) as they are limit points qed" be invalid? I know it is, but I don't know why

Comment: @ThunderHex By definition, a subset $U\subseteq S$ is open in $S$ when there is an open set $B$ in $A$ such that $U=B\cap S$. It follows also that if $B$ is closed in $A$, then $B\cap S$ is closed in $S$. The lines are disjoint - isn't that obvious since they have different $x$-coordinates? What is $U$ in your last question?

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks so much, I understand that whole part now. Just on $(0,0)$ being an interior point, the argument confuses me a bit. Why exactly does the infinite lines part ensure that $(0,0)$ is an interior point? When you say 'it contains nearby points of $A$' I don't fully understand. I understand how they are both limit points by the sequence converging - is what you did proving they are both limit points? The wording is just maybe different to what I'm used to so I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @ThunderHex Reworded that part of the answer. I see the role of SE as giving the main ideas rather than $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs.